# No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - Flutter Web project

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-web

I'm getting this error when running the project.
It has started after I migrated my project to another Google Account(I had to create all firebase configs(etc) on this account again).

Here is my index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!--
    If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
    href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.

    The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for
    it to work correctly.

    Fore more details:
    * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base
  -->
  <base href="/web/">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="Foxy Admin Panel">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Foxy Admin Panel">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>

  <title>Foxy Admin Panel</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
</head>
<body>

<!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.9.1/firebase-app.js"></script>

<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.9.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

  <!-- Firebase Firestore SDK -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.2/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
  <!-- Firebase Messaging SDK -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.2/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
  
  <!-- Firebase project configuration -->

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.4/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.4/firebase-storage.js"></script>



  <!-- This script installs service_worker.js to provide PWA functionality to
       application. For more information, see:
       https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers -->
  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener('flutter-first-frame', function () {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('flutter_service_worker.js');
      });
    }
  </script>
 <!-- Override the web renderer at runtime: -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // Set your option below
    let useHtml = true;
    // Check the option value
    if(useHtml) {
      window.flutterWebRenderer = "html";
    } else {
      window.flutterWebRenderer = "canvaskit";
    }
  </script>

<script>

  // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
  measurementId: ""
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);

</script>


  <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zeq3L78p/

If I just change the configs from firebase to my old account, it works straightaway.
Do you have any idea what is happening?

Comment: have you tried clean building your app with `flutter clean` and then ran `flutter create .` with your new account which you want to use for your current project

Comment: I have tried flutter clean, but didn't work. :(
And flutter create I think that wouldn't be a good choice since I already have a project built with some pages developed, I just need to change the firebase, which should be easy. :(